# VSTS build agent can't download VSTS private packages

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I am trying to add a build definition for a project that has private nuget packages hosted in VSTS. The local build works just fine but when I try to build it with an on premise build agent I get the following error:
[image]

The agent runs behind a proxy and in the build definition i have the following settings:

[image]

This is driving me mad please HELP !

Comment: Can you show the detail logs by setting `system.debug` as `true`? And what if you queue the build with Hosted agent?

Comment: Have you set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables to configure the proxy?

Answer (score 0):

The issue should related to your network environment on your build agent, such as firewall, proxy. You could also give a try with using the same Nuget task on an agent which has Visual Studio installed and in the same network environment, this will narrow down the error related to the proxy or not.

**Workaround:**

1) Copy nuget.exe to c:\nuget folder then added the folder to the PATH environment variable.

2) Copy nuget.exe to C:\B\1_tool\NuGet\4.0.0\x64 folder.

3) Create a dummy file called x64.complete in the {agent work folder}_tool\NuGet\4.0.0 folder and copy the nuget.exe file in the {agent work folder}_tool\NuGet\4.0.0\x64 folder.

Comment: i already have the nuget added to the path and the folder structure described in points 2 and 3 but still nothing... same error